# Render a sum attribute with Active Model Serializer or as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, active-model-serializers

The default code I have is `Lab.all` and it renders perfect json when I just Lab.all.to_json like so

```
{"id":1,"lab_id":1,"test_id":2,"price_cents":20000,"duration":null,"created_at":"2016-02-26T14:40:40.825Z","updated_at":"2016-02-26T14:40:40.825Z"}
```

I have the following scope:

`@lab_tests = LabTest.group(:lab).sum(:price_cents)` and it returns the following as json :

```
{"#\u003cLab:0x007f8e0a44afa8\u003e":20000}
```

How can I make it render json like so:

```
  {"id":1,"lab_id":1,"test_id":2,"price_cents":20000,"duration":null,"created_at":"2016-02-26T14:40:40.825Z","updated_at":"2016-02-26T14:40:40.825Z", "price_cents":200000 }
```

I've tried added a `.select` parameter to my scope, but even that does not change anything.